# php upload file issue using array

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload

in my form I'm trying to upload multiple or single file using php. So my html table is look like this :

```
<tr>
<td width="142"><b>Docs</b>
<td width="142"><input type="file" name="files[]" id="project_docs1" class="docfile" /></td>
<td width="142"><input type="file" name="files[]" id="project_docs2" class="docfile" /></td>
<td width="142"><input type="file" name="files[]" id="project_docs3" class="docfile" /></td>
</td>
```

Now when I upload only one file it's showing me error message like : Invalid Format but it's should be accept one file. it's not require to must be upload all 3 files. Can you tell me why it's showing this error message called **Invalid Format** ? If upload all 3 files then it's working fine.

and when I press the upload button without upload any file it's showing me value 1 for `$noOfUpload` variable. why ?

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "txt", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 1024*100; //100 kb
$path = "project_docs"; // Upload directory
$error =  array();  // load error message
$files_name =  array(); // get uploaded file name

foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key => $name) {

    $size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key]. "<br>"; 
    $noOfUpload = count($name);

    if($noOfUpload <= 0){
        $error[] =  "Upload your document/s<br>";
    }elseif(!in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats)){
        $error[] = "invalid file formate : $name<br>";

    }

    //$name = md5(uniqid()) . '-' . htmlspecialchars_decode($name);
    $files_name[] = "$name";

}

if(!empty($error)){
    foreach ($error as $e) {
        echo "<div class='error'>$e</div>";
    }   
}else{
    foreach ($files_name as $fn) {  
        echo "$fn<br>";
    }       
}
```

You help is more appreciate. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    if (isset($_FILES))
    {
        $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "txt", "bmp");
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++)
        {
           if (in_array(pathinfo($FILES['files']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats))
          {
             $tmp_path = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
             if ($tmp_path != "")
             {
                 if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_path, $new_path))
                 {
                     //Handle other code here
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     $error[] = ""; //your error handling
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 $error[] = ""; //your error handling
             }
         }
         else
         {
             $error[] = "invalid file formate : $name<br>";
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Ok, I'm trying with this.

Comment: @creativeartbd please check the edit, `$_FILES['files'] as $file`

Comment: @creativeartbd the way you are using multiple uploads will return different type of array, my above given code will work for `<input type='file' name='files[]' multiple='multiple' />`... by using this you can select multiple files in a single file selector by using the `ctrl key`.. and than use my above given code.

Comment: why this line of code is true : $file =  $_FILES['files']['name'];
 if(isset($file) && !empty($file)){
  echo "hello file";
 }else{
  echo "no file";
 }

Comment: it's showing "hello file" (for example) without upload any file.

Comment: why it's return : Undefined variable: FILES in several lines?

Comment: in this `pathinfo($FILES['files']['name'][$i]` please replace with `pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]` by mistake I missed one `underscore` in `$_FILES`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is run for whole array either it's blank or not. First, count your array then run your code upto that count.

Comment: if he doesnt select the file than also the count of the array will be 3, he have to check the `name` or other variables of the file is set or not..

Comment: if he doesn't select the file than the count of an array will be 0.
like

$array_count = $_FILES['files'][$i]['name'];
count(array_filter($array_count));

Here $i is total count of files array

Answer (score 0):

```
    <tr>
     <td width="142"><b>Docs</b>
     <td width="142"><input type="file" name="files[]" id="project_docs1" class="docfile" /></td>
    </tr>
```

PHP Code:

```
    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "txt", "bmp");
    $max_file_size = 1024*100; //100 kb
    $path = "project_docs"; // Upload directory
    $error =  array();  // load error message
    $files_name =  array(); // get uploaded file name

    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key => $name) {

    $size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key]. "<br>"; 
    $noOfUpload = count($name);

    if($noOfUpload <= 0){
        $error[] =  "Upload your document/s<br>";
    }elseif(!in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats)){
        $error[] = "invalid file format : $name<br>";

    }

    //$name = md5(uniqid()) . '-' . htmlspecialchars_decode($name);
    $files_name[] = "$name";

}

if(!empty($error)){
    foreach ($error as $e) {
        echo "<div class='error'>$e</div>";
    }   
}else{
    foreach ($files_name as $fn) {  
        echo "$fn<br>";
    }       
}
```